# How to pin specific C++ compiler path depends on OS

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to pin specific gcc path and version depends on the OS, because on macos it's not easy to use old version of gcc especially on m1, so it always use the one from xcode. Do you know how I can do this? I was checking Bazel toolchains and platform but it still not straightforwards for me...

Comment: If you want to pin a specific requirement (in your case GCC path and version), you can use Bazel toolchains and platform configurations. These set of instructions can be given in .bazelrc file. Bazel toolchain configuration doc can be found [here](https://bazel.build/extending/toolchains)